# Error when running maven generated executable jar

Tags: maven-2, jar, executable

I'm having (a strange) problem when executing a maven generated executable jar:

```
user@host$ java -server -jar MyJar.jar 

Error
```

(and nothing more than this!!!)

Do you have any idea what this king of error comes from ?

In my pom.xml, I copy all the dependencies to a lib folder with:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}/${artifactId}-${version}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                 </execution>
            </executions>
       </plugin>
```

And then I generate a .jar including the classpath (+ a prefix pointing to the lib folder):

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}/${artifactId}-${version}/bin</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>MyJar</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                           com.company.package.Main
                        </mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The generated MANIFEST.MF seems to contain the proper classpath.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Which JVM are you using? Is the content of the Jar file (besides MANIFEST.MF) matching what you expect?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.6.0_03-b05, mixed mode)


Yep... the content is exactly what I was expecting

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't saying much and this is indeed weird. Are you using Sun JDK?

Anyway, I don't really get how the dependencies get bundled into the final JAR with your setup and I don't think it contains everything required (I may be wrong of course).

Actually, I wouldn't even try to fix your current setup. To create an executable jar, you should prefer the assembly plugin. See [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832853/is-it-possible-to-create-an-uber-jar-containing-the-project-classes-and-the-pro/1834905#1834905) for example. Please modify your `pom.xml` with the suggested configuration (this will take 30 seconds) and try again. Then, please update your question with the new result/error, the `pom.xml` and the manifest.

Comment: I'm actually using the assembly plugin to copy configuration files and some deployment scripts.  

I don't even know if it's possible to bundle dependencies within the jar. In any case I prefer to keep them outside because I've quite a number of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Maven repository, rebuilt all the maven dependencies and somehow the issue was solved.

I've no idea how this happened, because I was just able to run without the jar ...

But thanks for your help anyway