# How to merge module jars to a single jar in Maven2?

Tags: maven-2

I have a maven2 project with several jar modules, build the project will get .jar archives for each module in the directory modules/XYZ/target/XYZ-x.x.x.jar

Now, if my project P is of version P-p.q.r, and I want to generate a single jar P-p.q.r-all.jar with all sub-modules included in, how should I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you want to achive is called *uber jar*. This module has to have dependecies of all others submodules you want to package into one jar. If you create another submodule that will produce a desired artifact it can be built in reactor with all its dependencies but if it will be a separate project that you have to install all uber jar dependecies.

```
| parent
| -- submodule1
...
| -- submoduleN
| -- uberjarSubmodule
```

Uber jar can be done by using:

1. [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) - in your case you have to remember to exclude transitive dependecies from your modules

   ```
   <project>
   ...
   <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.2</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>shade</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <artifactSet>
               <excludes>
                 <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                 <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                 <exclude>jmock:jmock</exclude>
                 <exclude>xml-apis:xml-apis</exclude>
               </excludes>
             </artifactSet>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   ...
   </project>
   ```
2. [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) - in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832853/is-it-possible-to-create-an-uber-jar-containing-the-project-classes-and-the-pro) question you'll find a detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you are going to ship this, if your jar is a library that you want other developers to download and use via maven. You should specify these as [dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/howto.html) in the projects pom.

If you are trying to ship something to an end-user who just wants to grab the binary and use your project, you could try using the [assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/howto.html) plugin to package your project. With this plugin you can package a jar alongside its dependencies. It won't put it all in a single jar file, but assuming you configure the users classpath correctly it shouldn't matter.