# java library inside jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I have created mytest.jar file with library that contains near 30 library files also jar.
Is it possible to put all library jars inside mytest.jar so that I need to distribute only 1 jar?
May be it can be done using manifest?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an "uber" jar containing the project classes and the project dependencies as jars with a custom manifest file ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832853/is-it-possible-to-create-an-uber-jar-containing-the-project-classes-and-the-pro)

Comment: Splitting up/re-packaging API Jars might go against the distribution license.  If this is for a desktop application, [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is a better approach to the entire problem of launching an app.  It is the 'one click' solution for the end user, and even better, it can not only server up the extra Jars as they are needed by the user, but also offers automatic updates should any of them change!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not out of the box. However, [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) provides a solution. It works fine for standalone apps, which is what I assume you' re making.

If you're making an applet instead, One-Jar won't work.

Answer (score 8):

Loading classes from jars-inside-jars is not possible with the standard Java classloader.  However it is possible using a custom classloader, this is how for example [UberJar](http://classworlds.codehaus.org/uberjar.html) works.

The [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) takes a different approach.  It will unpack all the jars you depend on, and pack them (along with your own classes) into one big jar.   Then the normal classloader can be used.  This is simpler, and is also possible without maven using [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).

Comment: need to be extra careful while using `maven shade plugin` or unpackaing all jars and repacking as one , as two jars might have common files files and one jar contents might get overwritten by another

Comment: The shade plugin allows renaming of packages (ie "shading") to avoid this - but yes, you do have to be careful.

Comment: It's pretty amazing that someone created that package.  I thought about doing that once and its good to know someone else created it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one uses a jar repacking tool like `jarjar` for this purpose.

Comment: @Lorenzo to what Heiko already added, here is the link: http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/    Please note that this is a java constraint and you probably would be better off by having these jars separate and adding them to classpath.