# Java command too long to run

Tags: java, jar, console-application

I've a Java console application with a lot of dependencies. I've to run it in production, so I created a runnable jar. The fact is that in order to run it, I need to write something like this:

```
java -classpath C:\Users\dandini\workspace\detror\target\classes;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.10\mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.2.4.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.0.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.2.4.Final\hibernate-core-4.2.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.15.0-GA\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\20030825.184428\commons-dbcp-20030825.184428.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\20030825.183949\commons-pool-20030825.183949.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\c3p0\c3p0\0.9.1.2\c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.6\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.6.6\jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.6\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\dandini\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\20020423\commons-httpclient-20020423.jar uk.co.dandini.Detrot uk.co.dandini.Detrot
```

Isn't there a shorter way? How is it usually deployed and run in production?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's packed into an executable JAR which contains a manifest with a classpath which Java uses to load classes: [How To Make A Java Exe File Or Executable JAR File](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/).

Or you could created your own loader which sets the classpath for your app as it's done in [Maven AppAssembler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) (recommended).

Answer (score 1):

You are using maven, so it's very easy. Probably the best option is to build a standalone "uberjar" which will contain all the dependencies, and will be runnable with just

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

Please refer to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1834905/1103872).

Answer (score 0):

you add the dependencies to the MANIFEST file
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html