# How to merge local jars using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a requirement to merge some jar into a common jar using maven. My system looks like as follows

```
first 
    |_ out 
        |-- jar1.jar
        |-- jar2.jar

second
    |--out
        |-- jar3.jar
        |-- jar4.jar
```

I wants to merge those 4 jar into one jar and place them in

```
first 
    |-- out
            |-- msg
```

I tried to use maven-shade plugin but I am not sure how to provide the path to those jar

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                   <artifact>jar1:jar1</artifact>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**</include>
                   </includes>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                   <artifact>jar2:jar2</artifact>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**</include>
                   </includes>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                   <artifact>jar4:jar4</artifact>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**</include>
                   </includes>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                   <artifact>jar3:jar3</artifact>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**</include>
                   </includes>
                </filter>
              </filters>            
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

If there is any other way I am open for that.

Comment: Try to give a look at Maven overlays, I just heard about them, they may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put jar files into another jar file, -jar files don't work that way. What you need is for all of the contents of all of the jar files to be extracted, and then zipped up again into one jar.

**Edit** :
`<include>` : instruct it what dependencies to pull into the uber JAR

`<include>groupId:artifactId</include>`

`<excludes>`: excludes some stuff from the target JAR that shouldn't be in there - such as JAR metadata, ant build files, text files, etc

something like this

```
 <configuration>
    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
      <artifactSet>
         <includes>
            <include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
            <include>net.sf.trove4j:trove4j</include>
            <include>org.mvel:mvel2</include>
            <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</include>
            <include>joda-time:joda-time</include>
          </includes>
        </artifactSet>
        <filters>
           <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/license/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                    <exclude>NOTICE</exclude>
                    <exclude>/*.txt</exclude>
                    <exclude>build.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: How can I achieve this using maven ?

Comment: if they are module jar's have a look at maven-shade-plugin or maven-assembly-plugin have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832853/is-it-possible-to-create-an-uber-jar-containing-the-project-classes-and-the-pr)

Comment: I am trying to use maven-shade-plugin but I am not sure how to point to the jar to be included.