# maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nu/pattern/OpenCV error

Tags: java, maven, opencv, intellij-idea

I am using https://github.com/patternconsulting/opencv to include **opencv** 3.2.0 in my **maven** **java** project.

The issue that I am facing is that when i use `mvn install` to generate a jar file and then run the jar file `java -jar app.jar` i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nu/pattern/OpenCV
    at com.example.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.pattern.OpenCV
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

below is an extract of my pom.xml file

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <mainClass>com.example.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and below is an extract of my class that has the main method:

```
public class Application {

    static {
        OpenCV.loadShared();
    }


    public Application() throws Exception {
      // some code here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Application();
    }
```

any idea what might be causing this to happen and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies are not automatically added to your jar file, only your own code.

You have several options because you are not the first to have this problem.  At your current skill level I would suggest looking into creating an uber-jar instead (so all your dependencies go in your jar file too).

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1834905/53897 which details how to go from here.